# How to make simple profiling tool for OpenCL programs?

Tags: profiling, opencl

I have a task to make a **simple** profiling tool (winOS) for performance/timing/event analysis of OpenCL programs. Can someone give advice how to start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest one and works accurately on all platforms:

```
  cl_event perfEvent;
  cl_ulong start=0, end=0;
  float t_kernel;

  /* Enqueue kernel */
  clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(commandQueue, kernel, 1, NULL, globalWorkSize, localWorkSize, 0, NULL, &perfEvent);
  clWaitForEvents( 1, &perfEvent );

  /* Get the execution time */
  clGetEventProfilingInfo(perfEvent, CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_START, sizeof(cl_ulong), &start, NULL);
  clGetEventProfilingInfo(perfEvent, CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_END, sizeof(cl_ulong), &end, NULL);
  t_kernel = (end-start)/1000000.0f;
  std::cout << t_kernel << std::endl;
```

Comment: This is helpful! I was wondering is it possible to implement this somehow **outside** of the OpenCL program, to make simple application with minimalistic GUI in Visual Studio? If yes, can you explain how could it be done (conceptually) so it could be used on different OpenCL programs.?

Comment: You meant you want to profile a binary/compiled file? in that case, you're dealing with symbols, maybe the command `nm -anC <binary>` will get you somewhere but im not sure if that's what you want. nm extracts all function symbols, so maybe you could start the time measurement after clEnqueueNDRangeKernel is called..

Comment: Yes, I meant to profile a compiled file, and I don't have a clue how profilers (sampling and instrumenting forms of profiling) work. Well, I assume that code from above is instrumenting form of profiling. For now I'll look into profiling methods and thank you for your effort

Comment: and maybe this will also get you somewhere: http://www.gremedy.com/gDEBuggerCL.php

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [AMD CodeXL](http://developer.amd.com/tools-and-sdks/opencl-zone/codexl/). It's free and it might be just what you are looking for. Inside CodeXL, use the Application Timeline Trace mode (Profile -> Application Timeline Trace), which executes a program and generates a visual timeline that displays OpenCL events like kernel dispatch and data transfer operations.